# get looping data from one data

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am using codeigniter.

I have two function in the model.

In the first function, I get all specific rows from one table. This is where I want to get all product details.

```
function getProduct() 
    {
        $shoes = 'SELECT pd.name,
                         pd.id, 
                         pd.price

                  FROM product_detail pd
                  LEFT JOIN product_sub_category psc
                  ON pd.sub_category_id = psc.id
                  WHERE psc.name = "Shoes"';

        $categoried = $this->db->query($shoes);
        return $categoried->result();
    }
```

While in the second function, I get all specific rows based on one row from the first function. This is where I want to get all images for each products.

```
function getImage()
    {
        $shoes = 'SELECT pim.file_name                      
                  FROM product_img pim
                  LEFT JOIN product_detail pd
                  ON pim.product_detail_id = pd.id
                  WHERE pim.product_detail_id = "'.$row->id.'"';

        $categoried = $this->db->query($shoes);
        return $categoried->result();

    }
```

But it gives me some errors.

Can someone please help me? Thanks for the help.

---

---

**[UPDATE]**

This is my Controller

In the controller, I identify `records` to get the product, and `recorded` to get the image.

```
function index() 
    {
        $this->load->model('site_model'); 

        $data = array();
        $query = $this->site_model->getProduct();
        $data['records'] = $query;

        foreach ($query as $row) 
            {
                $id = $row->id; // get ID
                $name = $row->name; // get ID
                $product_image = $this->site_model->getImage($id); // invoke the second method feeding that ID
                $data['recorded'] = $product_image;
            }
        $this->load->view('mothershop', $data);

    }
```

This is my Model

```
function getProduct() 
    {
        $shoes = 'SELECT pd.name,
                         pd.id, 
                         pd.price

                  FROM product_detail pd
                  LEFT JOIN product_sub_category psc
                  ON pd.sub_category_id = psc.id
                  WHERE psc.name = "Shoes"';

        $categoried = $this->db->query($shoes);
        return $categoried->result();
    }


function getImage($id)
    {
        $shoes = 'SELECT pim.file_name                      
                  FROM product_img pim
                  LEFT JOIN product_detail pd
                  ON pim.product_detail_id = pd.id
                  WHERE pim.product_detail_id = "'.$id.'"';

        $categoried = $this->db->query($shoes);
        return $categoried->result();

    }
```

This is my View of mothershop.php

In this section, I call the `records` and `recorded`

```
foreach ($records as $row) 
    {
        echo "<div>".$row->name."</br>";
            foreach ($recorded as $rowed)
                {
                    echo "<img src='".base_url()."upload/thumbs/".$rowed->file_name."'/>";
                }
        echo "</div>"; 
    }
```

However, I don't know why, it only get the same image for each products.

But if i print the `$product_image` in the controller, it gives me different images for each products.

What is wrong here?

Thanks in advance for @Ghost

Comment: One of the errors is Undefined variable: row in the line 'WHERE pim.product_detail_id = "'.$row->id.'"';'

Comment: Apparently the $row object doesn't exist. Where do you declare $row?

Comment: most likely because you haven't fed that id. just provide it in your second function argument `function getImage($id)`. then use `$id` on the query. currently, its out of scope

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since that `$row->id` is solely depending on the first fetching method, currently, its out of scope. In order to use that ID from the first method, just add an argument on the second method and use that to the second query. More like this:

```
function getImage($id)
```

Then you can use it on the second method.

Since you haven't shown any code on how you are using your methods. Consider this example:

First method usage (Controller):

```
$this->load->model('Super_model');
$products = $this->Super_model->getProduct();
foreach($products as &$row) {
    $id = $row->id; // get ID
    $product_image = $this->Super_model->getImage($id); // invoke the second method feeding that ID
    if(!empty($product_image)) { // if it exists
        $row->file_name = $product_image->file_name; // add another property which is file_name on that first fetched data
    }
}
```

Model method:

```
function getImage($id)
{
    $shoes = "SELECT pim.file_name                      
              FROM product_img pim
              LEFT JOIN product_detail pd
              ON pim.product_detail_id = pd.id
              WHERE pim.product_detail_id = '$id' ";

    $categoried = $this->db->query($shoes);
    return ($categoried->num_rows() > 0) ? $categoried->row() : null;   
}
```

That's the basic idea of it, we don't know what goes on and how you glue everything else on the controller, adjust it to fit into your codebase.

Comment: I am sorry, I edit your answer. Please review it. Thank you very much.

Comment: @klaudia no need to edit the answer, just edit the question then ping my name, anyways, in the end, before loading the data into the view, just add it. here is somewhat of an example http://pastebin.com/14gvrP9C

Comment: Please read my update question, Ghost. I face another problem here.

Comment: @klaudia no, just follow what i've written up, this should add the file name in the first loop for each product already, thats why in the controller i've already setup `foreach($products as &$row) {` (reference) then inside the loop `$row->file_name = $product_image->file_name;` so that in your view when the data is loaded, you should be able to use `->file_name`

Comment: @klaudia use the one i've setup in the pastebin, no need for that `recorded` loop, the `->file_name` already inside the `records`

Comment: Man, I need you to help me here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29344175/mapping-query-in-two-different-model-loop-all-query-codeigniter

Comment: @klaudia i can't answer right now, i'm in need of sleep and probably busy tomorrow, but i can't imagine having to fetch all thousands of rows, then on top of that having to query another set of each rows on each of those, it'll be painfully slow, you could try to join those two operations into one query instead. you're trying to get how many those registered who logged in right (the count of those who logged in)?

Comment: @klaudia plus, i'd add the `sql` tag, maybe master DB users like Gordon Linoff might stumble upon your question lol :D, they're good at formulating complex queries, (not just good working queries, but fast and optimized as well)